# java Как найти всех наследников класса в пакете?

Tags: java, наследование, рефлексия

Казалось бы ответ очевиден:

```
(new Reflections("package")).getSubTypesOf(SuperClass.class)
```

Однако эта конструкция находит не всех наследников, в случае, если иерархия разнесена на несколько пакетов.

Есть следующие классы:

```
package1.ParentClass extemds SuperClass
package2.ChildClass extends ParentClass
```

Пакеты `package1` и `package2` не вложенные.

Конструкция

```
(new Reflections("package1")).getSubTypesOf(SuperClass.class)
```

Ожидаемо вернёт `package1.ParentClass`

А вот конструкция

```
(new Reflections("package2")).getSubTypesOf(SuperClass.class)
```

Наш `package2.ChildClass` не вернёт, хотя это очевидный наследник `SuperClass`.

Я понимаю. что могу в ручную пробежаться по всем классам пакета и собрать нужные. Но неужели нет стандартного способа?

И ещё, объясните, почему по умолчанию `ChildClass` не находится? Для меня это было очень неожиданное поведение от `org.reflections.Reflections`.

**UPD**:
Изучил исходники ядра org.reflections, всё стало на свои места.
Если кратко, java именно так и реализует Reflections.
У каждого класса в рефлексии есть только ссылка на родителя. Поэтому поиск подклассов в любом случае перебор.
Почему в этом переборе нет супер классов из иных пакетов - вопрос отдельный. Так реализовано.

Для каждой конкретной задачи нужно использовать оптимальное решение. Но хотелось бы услышать о уже существующих решениях, которые позволяют найти всех потомков, кроме java org.reflections.

**UPD**: Ещё один интересный и нетрудоёмкий способ.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("package1", new SubTypesScanner())
Set<Class<?>> subTypes = new HashSet<>();
for (String className : reflections.getStore().get(SubTypesScanner.class.getSimpleName()).values()) {
    try {
        Class subType = Class.forName(className);
        if (SuperClass.class.isAssignableFrom(subType)) {
            subTypes.add(subType);
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Этого не может быть:)", e);
    }
}
return subTypes;
```

Данное решение перебирает все классы пакета (кроме наследников object)

```
reflections.getStore().get(SubTypesScanner.class.getSimpleName()).values()
```

и проверяет на то, что они являются наследником или реализуют SuperClass

```
SuperClass.class.isAssignableFrom(subType)
```

По производительности, по крайней мере, лучше, чем поиск по всем пакетам и последующая фильтрация

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> И ещё, объясните, почему по умолчанию ChildClass не находится?

Причина в том, что класс `ChildClass` является не прямым наследником `SuperClass`, а через класс `ParentClass`.

`Reflections` не уходит рекурсивно на проверку "родителей-родителей" и так далее, поэтому для обнаружения факта наследования через "промежуточные" классы необходимо загрузить пакеты со всеми "промежуточными" классами. В данном случае для того чтобы определить факт наследования `ChildClass` от `SuperClass` необходимо так же загрузить `ParentClass`. Лишние классы из полученного множества(Set) можно отфильтровать по имени пакета.

```
(new Reflections("package1","package2"))
       .getSubTypesOf(SuperClass.class)
       .stream()
     .filter(c->c.getPackage().getName().equals("package2")).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

---

1) Если неизвестен пакет "package1" то можно загрузить реализации из всех пакетов и потом отфильтровать по нужному пакету "package2":

```
Set<Class<? extends SuperClass>> s = new Reflections(
                ClasspathHelper.forClass(SuperClass.class))
                .getSubTypesOf(SuperClass.class)
                .stream()
                .filter(c->c.getPackage().getName().equals("package2"))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

или

```
Set<Class<? extends SuperClass>> s = new Reflections(
                new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClass(SuperClass.class))
                        .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().excludePackage("package2")))
                .getSubTypesOf(SuperClass.class);
```

2) В качестве более производительной альтернативы можно воспользоваться стандартными средствами “java core” и получить все файлы-классы пакета и их уже рекурсивно проверить на наличие искомого наследника.

```
public static Set<Class<?>> loadClasses(String packageName)
        throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
    URL resource = Thread.currentThread()
            .getContextClassLoader()
            .getResource(packageName.replace('.', '/'));
    File directory
            = new File(resource.getFile());
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        return classes;
    }
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
        return classes;
    }
    for (File file : files) {
        //в другие пакеты уходить ненужно
        if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
            classes.add(Class
                    .forName(String.format("%s.%s",
                            packageName,
                            file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().indexOf(".")))));
        }
    }
    return classes;
}
```

---

```
  public static boolean checkAllParents(Class<?> type, Class<?> hasParentType) {
        Class<?> parent = type.getSuperclass();
        if (parent == Object.class) {
            return false;
        }
        if (parent.getClass() == hasParentType.getClass()) {
            return true;
        }
        return checkAllParents(parent, hasParentType);
    }
```

---

```
Set<Class<?>> s = loadClasses("package2").stream()
                .filter(i->checkAllParents(i, SuperClass.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: "package1" в общем случае неизвестен. Видимо только перебор ручками...

Comment: "Причина в том, что класс ChildClass является не прямым наследником SuperClass а через класс ParentClass" - это не ответ. Это следствие из рассуждений в "вопросе". Да, я это заметил, а почему так происходит?

Comment: Так происходит потому, что Reflections не уходит рекурсивно на проверку "родителей-родителей" и т.д., а почему он не уходит это реализация Reflections (см. в исходниках). Посмотрите в сторону метода getSuperclass класса Class если его вызывать рекурсивно по всей иерархии наследования то будет работать как нужно.

Comment: Уже посмотрел. Я ответ плюсанул. Но можете эту информацию в ответ добавить?